# Angular v4 build fails with crypto-js

Tags: node.js, angular

Angular v4 build is failing and outputs the error below. I am using NodeJS v8.4.0.
It did not work even after clearing the cache. I am using following versions

"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",

"typescript": "^2.9.1",

angular v4.4.7

[image]

Comment: What is angular version?

Comment: @PardeepJain v4.4.7